# Capybara not finding meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Capybara 2.1.0 doesn't seem to find any meta tags:

```
(rdb:1) p page.find 'meta'
*** Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception: Unable to find css "meta"
```

even when they appear in `page.source`:

```
(rdb:1) p page.source
"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>MyTitle</title>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>\n<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>\n<meta name='description'>\n\n..."
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The solution was to use `:visible => false` either in `find` or in `have_selector`:

```
page.should have_css 'meta[name="description"]', visible: false
```

or:

```
page.find 'meta[name="description"]', visible: false
```

Comment: Just one tiny side note: quotes for the value are optional in this case, i.e. it could be just `'meta[name=description]'`. Not sure whether it is OK for the original author if I change this.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to check more specific meta, including the description text, etc:

https://gist.github.com/Lordnibbler/6247531

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_meta do |name, expected|
  match do |actual|
    has_css?("meta[name='#{name}'][content='#{expected}']")
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    actual = first("meta[name='#{name}']")
    if actual
      "expected that meta #{name} would have content='#{expected}' but was '#{actual[:content]}'"
    else
      "expected that meta #{name} would exist with content='#{expected}'"
    end
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_title do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    has_css?("title", :text => expected)
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    actual = first("title")
    if actual
      "expected that title would have been '#{expected}' but was '#{actual.text}'"
    else
      "expected that title would exist with '#{expected}'"
    end
  end
end
```

Then, look up meta like so:

`page.should have_meta(:description, 'Brand new Ruby on Rails TShirts')`

Borrowed with love from Spree: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/testing_support/capybara_ext.rb

Comment: Nice matcher. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Welcome, FYI I believe these have been added as part of Capybara core in 2.1

Comment: @professormeowingtons I tried the `have_meta` but does not work. Could you elaborate more about how to use it? And how about meta og tags? This should work, but doesn't: https://gist.github.com/JuanitoFatas/6421405 Thanks.

Comment: Quick note. You should do `has_css?("meta[name='#{name}'][content='#{expected}']", visible: false)` instead to force capybara to look into non visible elements.

Comment: You also need to add `visible: false` to the call to "first" if you want this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution did not work in 2021, but the following did

```
page.find('//head/meta[name="description"]', visible: false)[:content]
```

According to https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element

> Element also has access to HTML attributes and other properties of the
> element:
>
> bar.value
> bar.text
> bar[:title]