# RSpec Rails wont find my meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, meta-tags

I am just writing a couple of test and I want to make sure that I can test that some meta tags are on the page.

```
describe "article", :type => :feature do
  it "has correct meta tags", js: true do
    love_article = FactoryGirl.create(:love_article, title: 'Kitten Takes Over the World!', created_at: "Sat, 30 May 2015 12:12:21 -0400", updated_at: "Mon, 01 Jun 2015 12:12:44 -0400")
    visit "/articles/#{love_article.slug}"
    page.source.should have_selector('title', text: 'Kitten Takes Over the World!', visible: false) # this is found 
    expect(page).to have_selector('pubdate', text: '05/30/15 12:12:21 PM', visible: false) # This is not found
    # ERROR 
    # page.source.should have_selector('pubdate', text: '5/30/15 12:12:21 PM', visible: false)
    # RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find css "pubdate" with text "5/30/15 12:12:21 PM" but there were no matches from /Users/moiseszaragoza/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.0.4/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
  end
end
```

now when I add a debugger and I do  `page.source`
I get

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>\n
    <title>Kitten Takes Over the World!</title>\n
    <link rel=\ "stylesheet\" media=\ "all\" href=\ "/assets/application.css\">\n


    <meta content=\ "Kitten Takes Over the World!\" property=\ "og:title\">\n
    <meta content=\ "http://127.0.0.1:51840/articles/2015/05/30/kitten-takes-over-the-world\" property=\ "og:url\">\n
    <meta content=\ "Tell on Me is enabling parents to phone in complaints on unsuspecting teen drivers.\" property=\ "og:description\">\n
    <meta content=\ "/uploads/test/article/hero_image/42/test-image-file-employee.png\" property=\ "og:image\">\n
    <meta content=\ "article\" property=\ "og:type\">\n
    <meta content=\ "IE=edge,chrome=1\" http-equiv=\ "X-UA-Compatible\">\n
    <meta charset=\ "utf-8\">\n
    <meta content=\ "text/html\" http-equiv=\ "Content-Type\">\n
    <meta name=\ "section\">\n
    <meta content=\ "05/30/15 12:12:21 PM\" property=\ "og:pubdate\">\n
    <meta content=\ "05/30/15 12:12:21 PM\" name=\ "pubdate\">\n
    <meta content=\ "06/01/15 12:12:44 PM\" name=\ "lastmod\">\n
    <meta content=\ "Joe Shmoe\" name=\ "author\">\n
```

I guess to clarify I need to find this line from the source code

```
<meta content=\ "05/30/15 12:12:21 PM\" name=\ "pubdate\">\n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Capybara, you can do what was described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072241/3259320):

```
page.should have_css 'meta[name="description"]', :visible => false
```

or

```
page.find 'meta[name="description"]', :visible => false
```

Capybara by default does not work on elements not directly visible to the user (title is visible at the top of the browser/tab, so that was passing).

---

To check the content:

```
expect(page).to have_css 'meta[name="description"][content="expected_content"]', :visible => false
```

Comment: Thanks this does help out but if I wanted to test for the value of the meta[name="description"] would there be a way for that or should I just be happy that there is a tag

Comment: Also note that the part I added uses the `expect().to` syntax instead of the deprecated `object.should` syntax.